# Xamarin.Mac TextBox Update

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, textbox, textchanged

I have a form with a TextBox and a Label. My goal is to auto-update the label to the value of the TextBox each time I change something.

I know that in the .NET Framework there is a "TextChange" Event, which worked. But somehow I am not able to recreate this with with Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Changed` event and set the label's StringValue to the text field's StringValue:

```
nstextfield.Changed += (sender, e) =>
{
    label.StringValue = nstextfield.StringValue;
};
```